# MSB6006: “CL.exe” exited with code 2 when using openMP

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I try to run some openMP examples in visual studio, but when enable the /openMP the program could not work, return the error **"MSB6006: “CL.exe” exited with code 2"**. Here is the example:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { 
  #pragma omp parallel { 
     printf("Hello World... from thread = %d\n", omp_get_thread_num()); 
  } 
  return 0;
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Look at the Output, not Errors window.

Answer (score 5):

When you use openMP then the "two-phase name lookup" option cannot be used. This is indicated in Output Window where you can see this message:

*1>c1xx: error C2338: two-phase name lookup is not supported for C++/CLI, C++/CX, or OpenMP; use /Zc:twoPhase-*

To fix that go to "Project Properties"-> "C/C++" -> "Command Line" and add  **/Zc:twoPhase-** in "Additional Options" in bottom section and press Ok. That fixed my problem.
[image]

Comment: Confirming that this just worked for me with this error.

Comment: Also confirming that it helps. Should it be accepted as answer?